# Can't cast Object[] to an array of classes that use the parent classe's generic

Tags: java

I can't seem to create an array of class instances that have a field of a generic.

Like so:

```java
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
  } 
}

class Foo<K> {
  public Bar[] arr;

  Foo() {
    arr = (Bar[]) new Object[10];
  }

  void push(int index, K value) {
    arr[index].value = value;
  }

  class Bar {
    K value;
  }
}
```

[REPL](https://replit.com/@JimForstall/HotGrandioseMotion#Main.java)

Which gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LFoo$Bar; ([Ljava.lang.Object
```

But I do know for a fact that an array of generics, like so

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

can be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I do know for a fact that an array of generics, like so

> `T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[10];`

> can be created.

Nope. This is incorrect, and that is the root of your confusion.

You can't create 'generic arrays'. **Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination**. The JVM itself doesn't have a clue as to what they are. Most generics information poofs out of existence during the compilation step; the few generics that survive (in signatures), are treated as comments by the JVM: The JVM does not know what it means and doesn't care.

`T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[10];`

is a fancy way of telling the compiler not to complain, and to inject a few casts here and there. **That is all that line does**.

You've created a new object array. It's not a `T[]` array. The cast operator **does not convert anything**. It merely asserts types (is this thing indeed of that type? If yes, great, do nothing. If no, throw an exception). Given that this is by definition a runtime thing (if the compiler knows some expression is of some type, the cast obviously isn't needed), and generics fundamentally do not exist at runtime - then this cast operation truly does nothing. There's nothing to check. It cannot fail and has no bytecode. It is there **just** to tell the compiler that you take responsibility, as the compiler can no longer ascertain type safety for you.

What you've done is made an array of objects, and assigned it to a variable of type `T[]`. Local variables don't even exist in class files, they are 'compiled out', so to speak. Hence, you most definitely did not just 'make' a new 'array of T', in any sense you care to take that sentence.

So, having covered that:

Collections of any stripe (be they `java.util.List` or an array) **are invariant**. invariant is a concept in typing systems. You are presumably more used to covariant type systems: Java's basic type system is covariant. Covariant means: A subtype of a thing is just as good. In other words, this:

```
Object o = "hello";
```

is fine, because String is a subtype of Object, and is covariant - subtypes are fine. This isn't simply 'because the java spec says so' - it makes a more fundamental sense.

But in (writable) collections it just breaks down. Imagine that the 'component type' of a collection was covariant, then I could do this:

```
Integer[] integers = new Integer[10];
Number[] numbers = integers;
numbers[0] = 5.5;
System.out.println(integers[0]); // hmmmmm!!!
```

Go through those lines step by step - they explain why covariance *is wrong*. Hence, for the sake of collection types, java's typing system is *invariant*. You cannot assign an `Integer[]` to a `Number[]`. Unfortunately, 30 years ago when the initial java spec that introduced arrays was written, this wasn't thought through all that far and arrays have turned to be really really weird constructs as a consequence: Their toString, equals and hashCode implementations are well defined, but the definition is: These methods are effectively completely useless, and they can't grow or shrink.

collections do a much better job at it - you can't assign a `List<Integer>` list to a variable of type `List<Number>` either, but unlike with arrays, you can ask java for covariance and even contravariance: `List<? extends Number>` gives you covariance and the compiler acts accordingly - for example, you can't add anything to a `List<? extends Number>` because there's no way to know what you could possibly add - perhaps that variable is pointing at a `List<Integer>`, perhaps it is pointing at a `List<Double>`, and no value is both a Double and Integer simultaneously (except trivially and not useful, but for completeness: `null`, literally - which actually works; you can call `list.add(null)` if `list`'s type is `List<? extends Number>` - it is the only thing you can add).

One of those weird things about arrays is that any array can be assigned / is type-compatible with `Object[]`, even though this is wrong. It's a throwback in order to allow working with objects (what you really need is a `?[]` - just like you can have a `List<?>`, but that syntax did not exist at the time).

Arrays, unlike generics, are *not* a figment of the compiler's imagination: The runtime actually knows about them, tracks them, etcetera. You can e.g. do this:

```
Object[] o = new String[10]; // weird, but legal java.
o[0] = 5; // compiles, but throws an ArrayStoreException at runtime.
o.getClass().getComponentType(); // returns 'String.class'
```

and note how generics doesn't work like this at all:

```
List<Object> o = new ArrayList<String>(); // does not compile.
// .. but for funsies let's force the issue:
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List /* raw */ hack = strings;
List<Object> objects = hack; // compiles with warnings.
hack.add(5.0); // perfectly fine, compiles and runs without error.
String y = strings.get(0); // compiles perfectly fine.... but throws ClassCastException at runtime.
objects.get????? // there is no way to get 'String.class' from this thing. At all.
```

In other words, what you fundamentally want to do (treat an array of Dogs as an array of Animals) doesn't work - not because of java, but because of the universe: You can add parrots to an array of animal, hence why you can't treat an array of Dogs as an array of Animals. A java specific hacky thing with arrays is that you *CAN* treat an array of anything as an array of Object specifically (and *only* Object[], that is hardcoded in the spec), which is wrong and leads to all sorts of broken code, but it's in the language solely to give you an option to work with arrays as a generalized concept, because java 1.0 through 1.4 didn't have generics.

TL;DR: Do not use arrays. They are weird and mostly useless. Make `List<T>`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

The exception caused by this line :

```
arr = (Bar[]) new Object[10];
```

To simplify the explanation i just want to replace your code with this example :

```
public class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
   Bar b = (Bar) new Object();
  } 
}
class Bar{
}
```

This line        `Bar b = (Bar) new Object();` compile because `Bar` extends `Object` , an **this inheritence relation let your code compile**, but at `RunTime` Java find that you are trying to cast an instance of `Object` class ( created using `new Object()`) ,and that's impossible because `Object` is a superType of `Bar` .

You did the same thing just you added the [ ].

With generics , any `T` class must extends (directly or indirectly) `Object` class , `T` can be Object himSelf , so the code compile and can throw a `ClassCastException` .