# When I implement Comparable interface, Java give cannot be cast to class exception while creating an array

Tags: java

```java
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{
    public T[] toArray() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] arrayOfList = ( T[]) new Object[numberOfEntries];
        Nodes currentNode = firstNode;
        for(int i =0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
            assert(currentNode.getNextNode() != null);
            arrayOfList[i] = currentNode.getData();
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        }
        return arrayOfList;
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class
> [LpatientManagementSystem.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in
> module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> [LpatientManagementSystem.Comparable; is in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

Comment: the same question exactly is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804642/cant-cast-object-to-an-array-of-classes-that-use-the-parent-classes-generic/71804689#71804689

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an `Object[]` to `T[]`.
You need to create an Array of T directly:

```
T[] arrayOfList = (T[]) Array.newInstance((Class<?>) getClass().getGenericSuperclass(), numberOfEntries);
```

First we get the class of T (`T.class`) which is `(Class<?>) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`.
Then we create an array with that class: `(T[]) Array.newInstance(**T.class**, numberOfEntries)`.
Since `T.class` is only available at Runtime, we need to use the previously shown reflection to get access to it.